# Atalhos de teclado em RibbonWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicação usando [WPF](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjy1pT6w8DNAhVBjJAKHQ0DCmkQFggeMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fpt.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWindows_Presentation_Foundation&usg=AFQjCNHcLA7Oz3WC0bLPXgkQPKt3L1lViQ&sig2=RdKW7g3oTaIyU19AMGCZKA&bvm=bv.125221236,d.Y2I) e janela baseada na [RibbonWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) da [RibbonControlsLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RibbonControlsLibrary/) e estou tendo problemas com o Gesture de "Ctrl+0", apenas com o "Ctrl+NumPad0" eu consegui realizar a ação através do teclado númerico, mas o diretamente o 0 não. Isso funcionou:

```
        <KeyBinding
            Command="{StaticResource RestaurarZoomHandler}"
            Gesture="Ctrl+NumPad0"/>
```

Já isso aqui, não funcionou:

```
        <KeyBinding
            Command="{StaticResource RestaurarZoomHandler}"
            Gesture="Ctrl+0"/>
```

Saberiam dize qual é o problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos ler a própria [documentação do KeyBinding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keybinding.aspx) (tradução Google).

> Com exceção das teclas de função e as teclas do teclado numérico, um válido KeyGesture deve conter exatamente um Key e um ou mais ModifierKeys . Teclas de função e teclas do teclado numérico não exigem uma tecla modificadora, a fim de ser um válido KeyGesture . É possível especificar um inválido KeyGesture e um KeyBinding com um gesto associado inválido, seja através de XAML ou código. Por exemplo, não há validação que impede a criação e ligação de um KeyGesture que contém apenas uma chave de não funcionamento, ou apenas modificadores mas nenhuma chave. Tal KeyBinding nunca tentará invocar seu comando associado.

Em resumo, não podemos especificar as teclas modificadoras para uma tecla no teclado numérico. Por favor, use a tecla `NumPad0` ou apenas usar `Alt + 0` (o `Alt` plus as teclas numéricas `D0`).

Fonte: [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6ed48036-f532-47b2-b8e1-8bb00c524482/wpf-keybinding-of-alt0-does-not-work?forum=wpf)

#### Bônus:

Como bônus, deixarei [este pequeno projetinho](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2011/01/31/a-wpf-numeric-entry-control-with-pop-up-calculator-2/) de uma calculadora em **WPF**, onde utiliza o teclado numérico [System.Windows.Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.input(v=vs.110).aspx) para obter os dados do teclado.

Comment: Realmente, li sem atenção a documentação e acabou passando batido isso.